# How to modify Vaadin MessageInput textarea placeholder/button content?

Tags: vaadin, vaadin24

Why there's no direct way to modify the content of `MessageInput` :

1. placeholder content of textarea (I want to replace `Message` with `Your query here`)
2. send button text (I want to replace `Send` with `Search`)

[image]

This has to be dead simple and the whole point of moving away from regular input text with buttons. But now its far more difficult and has to jiggle with CSS and custom javascript to achieve anything.

How do I do this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can call setI18n and then pass a MessageInputI18n object:

```
input.setI18n(new MessageInputI18n().setMessage("Java Developer in Seattle").setSend("Search"));
```

https://vaadin.com/api/platform/24.4.0.alpha1/com/vaadin/flow/component/messages/MessageInputI18n.html

Comment: `MessageInput input = new MessageInput();`
  `input.getI18n().setMessage("Java Developer in Seattle").setSend("Search");`    ---> Gets me an error saying `NullPointerException` -- since `input.getI18n()` is null.

Comment: It is strange, but I had to do this way : `input.setI18n(new MessageInputI18n().setMessage("Java Developer in Seattle").setSend("Search"));`

Comment: No that's not strange. That's the way to use I18n with Vaadin. I update my answer. Sorry about that